# redshift create a field with value based on other column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, rank, flags

I need to create a flag field based on the value on second column.

```
ID1     ID2     FLAG
1       19      1
1       37      1
2       19      2
2       37      2
2       98      1
3       19      1
4       37      1
5       19      1
5       37      1
6       37      2
6       98      1
```

i.e.  when ID2 is 98 then flag is 1
else when they are in 19, 37 then 1
but when ID1 has all ID2 then 98 gets priority like for ID1 = 2 in the above example.

So far, I'm trying to group by, get max() then set value.
I tried RANK() method but rank should be same for 19, 37 and I'm unsure of how to do that.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your explanation really is not clear.  Is the third column what you are trying to generate?  Or is it already in the data?

Comment: yes, third field is what i need to generate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by id1
                          order by (id2 = 98) desc
                         ) as flag
from t;
```

Comment: will this give same rank for 19, 37 IDs?

Comment: @HarinieR . . . Yes.